# Path to the file Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've made a code that reads files from the folder and saves their paths.

```
sample_directory = []
sample_files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Samples'):
    sample_files.extend(filenames)
    break
paths = []    
for i in range(len(sample_files)):
    path = os.path.realpath(sample_files[i])
    paths.append(path)

sample_directory.append(sample_files)
sample_directory.append(paths)
print(sample_directory)
```

> [['smpl1.xlsx', 'smpl2.xlsx', 'smpl3.xlsx', 'smpl4.xlsx', 'smpl5.xlsx'], ['/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/smpl1.xlsx', '/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/smpl2.xlsx', '/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/smpl3.xlsx', '/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/smpl4.xlsx', '/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/smpl5.xlsx']]

The problem is that it skips one folder and the true path is:

> /Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/**Samples**/smpl1.xlsx

Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first loop only stores the filenames, without the root directory. After that, using `realpath` (or `abspath`) doesn't solve anything: the directory path information is already lost.

You don't need recursion, since you break at first iteration, so the best way would be to use `os.listdir` and append the path (and use `abspath` to convert to absolute path):

```
the_dir = "Samples"
paths = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(the_dir,filename)) for filename in os.listdir(the_dir)]
```

alternative with `glob.glob`:

```
import glob
paths = glob.glob(os.path.abspath("Samples/*"))
```

also note that instead of `abspath`/`realpath`, most of the time the `Samples` directory is relative to your python file. In that case, just do:

```
the_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Samples")
```

and drop all absolute/real path conversion. The advantage is that you can change directory/run the app from another directory and the "resource" files are still reachable.

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The `realpath` returns a relative filepath to `path` either from the current directory or from an optional start point.

Since you want the actual path of the file, use:

```
path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(dirpath,sample_files[i]))
```